# How to prevent Wordpress from retrieving data for the last 10 posts in the database?

Tags: database, query

According to the Query Monitor plugin, Wordpress is calling four queries for the last 10 posts in the database, starting with this to know the IDs:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The below and two other will then follow:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID IN (29,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18)
```

I'm using a custom template so I don't need this, is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are visiting the home page and it contains the WordPress Loop like below to query 10 recent posts.

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // Your loop code
    endwhile;
else :
    // not found template
endif;
?>
```

The number of posts can be managed from `settings->reading->Blog pages show at most.` from WordPress dashboard.
There you will see `10 posts` selected in the value. if you want to display 5 posts then change this value.

if you want to remove this query from home page then edit `index.php, frontpage.php or home.php` file depending upon your theme. Recommended way is to create a `page template` and do your thing there. [how to create page template in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/)